# How to make a python script become a unix command?

Tags: python, linux, unix, debian

**How do I make a python script a unix-able command?**

Let's say i have a python script:

```
print "hello foo bar"
```

and i want to call the python script like a normal linux command, something that people can:

```
deb www.myfoobar.com foobar
deb-src www.myfoobar.com foobar
sudo apt-get install foobar
```

Then after installation, something that someone can just call from terminal:

```
$ foobar
hello foo bar
```

Comment: That's a lot of steps.  Are you asking how to create a deb? How to host a deb on your website? How to store the script in a file?

Comment: All you have to do is to put the script at a System level searchable path and change its mode to execuatable.

Comment: @falsetru had answer how to store the script into a command. How do i create and host a deb?

Comment: You don't. Use [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) instead.

Comment: There are lots of online resources to explain how to create your own `deb` file and repository. A quick google search turns up, for example, http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/162 and http://www.impermium.com/blog/hosting-deb-packages-locally/, and many other options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put following shebang line at the top of the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Make a script executable using following command:

```
chmod +x foobar
```

Move the script to somewhere in the $PATH (for example: /usr/local/bin)

```
mv foobar /usr/local/bin
```

**From Rob:** For the creating and hosting a deb problem, you can use external services such as https://launchpad.net/ubuntu

Comment: This doesn't address how to run `sudo apt-get install`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a complete walk through for [creating an Ubuntu package and submitting it for consideration](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/packaging-new-software.html). Debian has it's own procedures. Of course if you just want to make a Python script into a Unix command then you might also just want to package it using setuptools, submit it to PyPi and let people `pip install <package>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to distribute your script, so you can download it, you have to create a **package** (.rpm on linux).

Comment: The native package format is `.rpm` on Redhat and similar distros. It is `.deb` on Debian, Ubuntu and distros derived therefrom.